# Compare multiple values in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I'd like to go from this:

```
if($var == 3 || $var == 4 || $var == 5 || $var =='string' || $var == '2010-05-16') {
   // execute code here
}
```

to this:

```
if($var == (3, 4, 5, 'string', '2010-05-16')) { // execute code here }
```

Seems very redundant to keep typing `$var`, and I find that it makes it a bit cumbersome to read.  Is there a way in PHP to do simplify it in this way?  I read on a post here that when using XQuery you can use the = operator as in `$var = (1,2,3,4,5)` etc.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Place the values in an array, then use the function in_array() to check if they exist.

```
$checkVars = array(3, 4, 5, "string", "2010-05-16");
if(in_array($var, $checkVars)){
    // Value is found.
}
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: One of the first responses, nice solution, and includes a link to the manual.  Thanks!

Comment: [As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with \[\]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so just `if(in_array($var, [3,4,5,"string","2010-05-16"])){...}` suffices.

Comment: PHP 5.4 doesn't _replace_ `array()` with `[]`

Answer (score 9):

If you need to perform this check very often and you need good performance, don't use a slow array search but use a fast hash table lookup instead:

```
$vals = array(
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    'Hi' => 1,
);

if (isset($vals[$val])) {
    // go!
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting solution.  I'll have to run a script or two to see how the speed compares, as I'm quite curious now.

Comment: Hmmmm ... over 6 years later and no conclusion?  One begins to suspect the code must be pretty slow.  :-)

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+performance+isset+vs.+in_array) for the performance comparison it seems `isset` indeed is much faster. There's also a post about it on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13483219/2199525

Answer (score 8):

```
if (in_array($var, array(3, 4, 5, 'string', '2010-05-16'))) {execute code here }
```

Or, alternatively, a switch block:

```
switch ($var) {
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 'string':
    case '2010-05-16':
        execute code here;
        break;
}
```

Comment: The first solution is excellent. The second option here works, just as the if statement I proposed works, but it's just as cumbersome I believe.  Instead of typing $var many times, have to type case many times.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `in_array()`.

```
if (in_array($var, array(3,4,5,"string","2010-05-16"))) { .... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `in_array()`

```
if(in_array($var,array(4,5,'string','2010-05-16',true)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alternative solution to the use of `in_array`:

In some cases it could be faster to set an array where the values are keys and then check with `isset()`

Example:

```
$checkVars= [3 => true, 
             4 => true, 
             5 => true, 
             "string" => true, 
             "2010-05-16" => true];

if(isset($checkVars[$var])
{
   // code here
}
```

**EDIT**: I have done some testing and it looks like this method is faster in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vals = array (3, 4, 5, 'string', '2010-05-16');
if(in_array($var, $vals)) {
  //execute code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and solved it by making this function:

```
function orEquals(){
    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach($args as $arg){
        if ($arg != $args[0]){
            if($arg == $args[0]){
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    unset($args);
}
```

then you can just call the function like this:

```
if(orEquals($var, 3, 4, 5, 'string', '2010-05-16')){
//your code here
}
```