# How to use if to match different text strings

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare multiple values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106382/compare-multiple-values-in-php)

I want to do something like this

```
if($abc="asdf","sdfg","dfgh") {
echo "Something";
}
```

What should I do? Do I have to use seperate rules with `||` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/in_array) for such purposes:

```
if (in_array($abc, array('asdf', 'sdfdg', 'qweqe'))) {
    // something
}
```

The third parameter of `in_array()` can be used to perform strict type checks between the needle and each item of the haystack, similar to `===`.