# Which conditional statement is correct?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Of the following, which conditional statement is best practice:

```
if ($_GET['type'] == 'user' || $_GET['type'] == 'salesmen')
```

or

```
if ($_GET['type'] == ('user' || 'salesmen'))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use the first one:

```
if ($_GET['type'] == 'user' || $_GET['type'] == 'salesmen')
```

The second one is a valid PHP ststement but it will produce unexpected results ( Not the output you are expecting ).

Comment: Alternatively, I've created an array with the elements 'user' and 'salesmen', then used a conditional using the in_array() function. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That should also work, that method is usually used when you have to compare with many values. You are welcome

Comment: The second one will not produce “unexpected” results, the result is well defined in PHP – it is just not what the OP _wants_.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried it? One simple try would point you that the second part will not work as you expected.

However, I would suggest `in_array()`

```
if (in_array($_GET['type'], array('user', 'salesmen'))) {
   //
}
```

or

```
$type = array('user', 'salesmen');
if (in_array($_GET['type'], $type)) {
    //
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in PHP5.4 they added short arrays so this is even cuter:
`if ( in_array($_GET['type'], ['user','salesmen']) ) {`

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct. In the second one you are actually comparing `$_GET['type']` with a boolean expression (`'user' || 'salesmen'`)

Answer (score 2):

In your second example

```
('user' || 'salesmen')
```

Will be evaluated first, which results in a boolean true. 
Resulting in the following expression to be evaluated for the first:

```
$_GET['type'] == true
```

Which may or may not be true. In this case that would be true if $_GET['type'] is 1, true, an object, a string, or anything else that evaluates to true. This aspect is hidden in your question, but I would like to highlight that it could be prevented by using the identity operator ([===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)).

Even prettier (imho):

```
$typeIsUser = $_GET['type']  === 'user';
$typeIsSalesMan = $_GET['type'] === 'salesmen';
if ($typeIsUser  || $typeIsSalesmen){
...
}
```

Or use in_array! The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is the valid one, the second one is not doing what you think it is.

You can find a full discussion of the various options to achieve this here:

[Compare multiple values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106382/compare-multiple-values-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you will want to do is make sure the parameter exists, otherwise you may see notices about a missing array index with a URL like `/page?foo=bar`:

```
if (isset($_GET['type'])) { ... }
```

Combining that with the rest of your code:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && ($_GET['type'] == 'user' || $_GET['type'] == 'salesmen')) { ... }
```

Alternatively:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && in_array($_GET['type'], ['user', 'salesmen'])) { ... }
```

#### Btw

This code:

```
if ($_GET['type'] == ('user' || 'salesmen'))
```

Compares `$_GET['type']` with `true`, yielding `true` for most values.