# Elegant way to shorten if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Any ideas how to shorten if statment in an elegant way.
My if statement:

```
 if(getfoo1() == getfoo2() &&  getfoo2() == 1)
 {

 }
```

**EDIT**:
I'm  looking for something like:

```
if(getfoo1() == getfoo2() ==1)
{
}
```

But I suppose we can't do this.

Comment: without more context it may be impossible to say for sure

Comment: This might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106382/compare-multiple-values-in-php#answer-4106407

Comment: actually nevermind @JavaSa, I wrote an elegant solution that I posted below.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = getfoo1();
$b = getfoo2(); // less operations, while it not produces duplicate calls

if($a == $b && $b == 1){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think it will be better to change the order of the condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
$variable = ((getfoo1() == getfoo2() && getfoo2() == 1) ? $value1 : $value2);
```

More elegant, combined:

```
$a = getfoo1();
$b = getfoo2();
$variable = (($a == $b && $b == 1) ? $value1 : $value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know the possible return values from the functions, if you assume they are integers then you can say:

```
$a = getfoo1();
$b = getfoo2();
if (($a * $b) === 1) { // strict equality for the win
    echo 'hi';
}
```

The result would only be true iff both `$a` AND `$b` are `1`.

Another way:

```
$both = array(getfoo1(), getfoo2());
// use array_diff_assoc so it checks multiple occurrences of the same value
$diffCount = count(array_diff_assoc($both, array(1, 1))); 
if ($diffCount === 0) {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Comment: What about if `$a != $b` ?

Comment: then his original statement would never even check the `$b == 1` part due to short circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$a = getfoo1();
$b = getfoo2();
if( intval($a && $b) === 1) {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Comment: by this you are checking for a true value instead of a value of 1 for both operands

Comment: Actually, this is the shortest, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Answer (score 0):

Since anyway `getfoo2() == 1` must be true, a better approach is to first check whether `getfoo2()` is equal to 1. If it false no matter about 2nd condition. But If you first check `getfoo1() == getfoo2()` and and then check `getfoo2() == 1` you have to check 2 conditions all the  times.

Therefore go for

```
$a = getfoo1();
$b = getfoo2();
if($b == 1 && $a == $b) 
{
     // logiv
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just an alternative to if-else-statement

Sometimes you need to put lots of if-else statements in code which causes some **readability** problems. The following technique might help you make your code more readable. It creates **type guards** as the if-statement does so you are not checking the same value twice. Also, this technique indicates the **intention** of our code more clearly

```
type MatchReturn<T, C, R> = Omit<
  Matcher<Exclude<T, C>, R>,
  'matchHandle' | 'match'
>;

type MatchHanle<T, C, R> = Omit<
  Matcher<Exclude<T, C>, R>,
  'matchReturn' | 'match' | 'get'
>;

export class MatcherOptions<T> {
  defaultValue: (() => T) | null = null;
  throwError = false;

  constructor(options?: Partial<MatcherOptions<T>>) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }
}
/**
 * Utilize the Matcher class to eliminate cumbersome if-else statements.
 */
export class Matcher<T, R> {
  private matchResult: (() => R) | null = null;
  private updated = false;

  /**
   * When the throwError parameter is set to true, an error will be thrown by get method if there is no match to the value.
   * @param value
   * @param throwError boolean
   */
  constructor(
    private readonly value: T,
    private readonly options: Partial<MatcherOptions<R>> = new MatcherOptions()
  ) {
    this.options = new MatcherOptions(options);
  }

  /**
   * Return true if the matchValue is identical to the value; otherwise, return false.
   * @param matchValue T
   * @returns boolean
   */
  match(matchValue: T): boolean {
    return matchValue === this.value;
  }

  /**
   * If the matchValue is equivalent to the value,
   * proceed to assign the result to the returnValue variable.
   * Subsequently, at the conclusion of the statement,
   * you can access the value stored in returnValue using the get method.
   * @param matchValue T
   * @param returnValue R
   * @returns R
   */
  matchReturn<C extends T>(
    matchValue: C,
    returnValue: () => R
  ): MatchReturn<T, C, R> {
    if (this.match(matchValue)) {
      this.matchResult = returnValue;
      this.updated = true;
    }
    return this as MatchReturn<T, C, R>;
  }

  /**
   * If the matchValue is equal to the value, proceed to invoke the provided handler function.
   * @param matchValue T
   * @param handler ()=>any
   * @returns Matcher
   */
  matchHandle<C extends T = T>(
    matchValue: C,
    handler: () => unknown
  ): MatchHanle<T, C, R> {
    if (this.match(matchValue)) {
      handler();
    }
    return this as MatchHanle<T, C, R>;
  }

  /**
   * Upon finalizing the matchReturn method chain, employ this method to retrieve the resultant output.
   * @returns R
   */
  get() {
    if (this.options.throwError) {
      if (!this.updated) {
        throw new Error(`We could not find mach for ${this.value}!`);
      }
    }

    if (this.options.defaultValue) {
      if (!this.updated) {
        return this.options.defaultValue();
      }
    }

    return this.reset();
  }

  private reset() {
    if (this.matchResult) {
      const result = this.matchResult();
      this.matchResult = null;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

#### Example

Let's use our matcher.

```
      type InputType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'; 
      type ReturnType= 100 | 200  | 300;


      const abcMatcher = new Matcher<InputType , ReturnType>('a');

      // result will be 100.
      const result = abcMatcher

        // Shows autocompletes for inputs and outputs
        .matchReturn('a', () => 100)
        .matchReturn('b', () => 200)
        .matchReturn('c', () => 200)

        // You are not allowed to check the same value again! 
        // Shows error message
        .matchReturn('a', () => 'letter a')

         // get the result
        .get();
```